# Plugin View Details Link

Tags: admin-menu

How do I get the [View details] link to appear on the Plugin admin page in the Description area?

The plugin is working fine, the version and authors (with links) show up fine, but no [View details] like most other plugins.

Perhaps I'm asking the wrong question, but I'm working on a plugin and I would like to show the readme.txt and screenshots like I see in so many plugins. How do I get this link to appear and show the contents of the readme.txt file?

I've been reading through Professional WordPress Plugin Development, but I can't find this reference. I can refer to an external URI, but I would like the nice and concise panel that shows on other plugins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 'View details' link in the installed plugins list table is only shown for plugins that are hosted in the WordPress.org plugin repository. If you take a look at the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php#L522) for `WP_Plugins_List_Table->single_row()`, you'll see that the details link is only generated if there's API data present, e.g. the slug is set:

```
// Details link using API info, if available
if ( isset( $plugin_data['slug'] ) && current_user_can( 'install_plugins' ) ) {
    $plugin_meta[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="thickbox" aria-label="%s" data-title="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( network_admin_url( 'plugin-install.php?tab=plugin-information&plugin=' . $plugin_data['slug'] .
            '&TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550' ) ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'More information about %s' ), $plugin_name ) ),
        esc_attr( $plugin_name ),
        __( 'View details' )
    );
} elseif ( ! empty( $plugin_data['PluginURI'] ) ) {
    $plugin_meta[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $plugin_data['PluginURI'] ),
        __( 'Visit plugin site' )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention if your plugin is/isn't hosted on WordPress.org, neither if you installed the plug-in from WordPress Plugin Directory or just a local ZIP copy of it (which is the equivalent of a private-hosted plug-in).

As already answered earlier the "View details" link appears only for the plugins which has the slug hosted at WordPress.org.

I just want to emphasize that there are situations when you may not see the "View details" even for a plug-in which is in fact hosted by WordPress.org.

How? In which situation?

Example: just imagine that your plug-in is hosted by them but actually you didn't installed the plugin from WordPress Plugin Directory, instead you installed a local ZIP file (a fresh copy of it while testing a new fix/tweak for instance).

In my example above the installed copy represents the same plug-in but is not installed from WordPress Plugin Directory. It was installed from a local ZIP file which is the equivalent of private-hosted plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to, you can hook into [`plugin_row_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugin_row_meta/) and add your own link.

The problem is that the parsed README is hosted on the WordPress Plugin Directory.
The standard "View Details" link includes `/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=plugin-information` which calls `http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/` by default.

## Solution / Workaround

1. Supply your own link.
2. (Optional) Hook into the WordPress API Response.

### Supplying your own link

Assuming you're in your main plugin file, add this:

```php
add_filter(
    'plugin_row_meta',
    function( $plugin_meta, $plugin_file, $plugin_data ) {
        if ( __FILE__ === path_join( WP_PLUGIN_DIR, $plugin_file ) ) {
            // Here you supply the link to your README. 
            // I've converted my `readme.txt` to HTML. More on that later...
            $url = plugins_url( 'readme.html', __FILE__ );

            // This is an adaptation of part of `WP_Plugins_List_Table->single_row()`.
            $plugin_meta[] = sprintf(
                '<a href="%s" class="thickbox open-plugin-details-modal" aria-label="%s" data-title="%s">%s</a>',
                add_query_arg( 'TB_iframe', 'true', $url ),
                esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'More information about %s' ), $plugin_data['Name'] ) ),
                esc_attr( $plugin_data['Name'] ),
                __( 'View details' )
            );
        }
        return $plugin_meta;
    },
    10,
    3
);
```

### Hooking into the WordPress API Response.

Again, assuming you're in your main plugin file, you have to add the link and hook into the API response:

```php
$slug = 'slug-of-your-plugin-or-some-id';

add_filter(
    'plugin_row_meta',
    function( $plugin_meta, $plugin_file, $plugin_data ) {
        if ( __FILE__ === path_join( WP_PLUGIN_DIR, $plugin_file ) ) {
            // This is an adaptation of part of `WP_Plugins_List_Table->single_row()`.
            $plugin_meta[] = sprintf(
                '<a href="%s" class="thickbox open-plugin-details-modal" aria-label="%s" data-title="%s">%s</a>',
                esc_url(
                    network_admin_url(
                        "plugin-install.php?tab=plugin-information&plugin=$slug&TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550"
                    )
                ),
                esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'More information about %s' ), $plugin_data['Name'] ) ),
                esc_attr( $plugin_data['Name'] ),
                __( 'View details' )
            );
        }
        return $plugin_meta;
    },
    10,
    3
);

add_filter(
    'plugins_api',
    function( $response, $action, $args ) {
        if ( 'plugin_information' === $action && $slug === $args->slug ) {
            return (object) array(
                // Mock the response from the WordPress Plugin Directory.
                // For an example request inspect
                // https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=plugin_information&request[slug]=classic-editor
            );
        }
        return $response;
    },
    10,
    3
);
```

### Appendix: Converting an existing README

If you've already written your `readme.txt` without realizing that it won't show (like myself...), you could convert it to HTML and use the first snippet from above.

Put this in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "readme": "grunt readme"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.6.1",
    "grunt-md2html": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-wp-readme-to-markdown": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

And this goes into your `Gruntfile.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        wp_readme_to_markdown: {
            your_target: {
                files: {
                    'README.md': 'readme.txt',
                },
            },
            options: {
                // Optional: Only if you want to include screenshots.
                screenshot_url: 'assets/{screenshot}.png',
            },
        },

        md2html: {
            your_target: {
                files: {
                    'readme.html': 'README.md',
                },
            },
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-wp-readme-to-markdown');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-md2html');
    grunt.registerTask('readme', ['wp_readme_to_markdown', 'md2html']);

};
```

Now run `npm install && npm run readme` and you'll see a `readme.html` in your plugin directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you rename the folder that the plugin files are contained in... WordPress will use your Plugin URI stated in the header of the main plugin file.