# Why isn't my readme.txt file being read

Tags: plugin-development, readme

When I select "View Details" of my plugin from the Dashboard > Plugins page, I get a blank description and no other tabs. I only have the Author and version on the right hand side, which comes from the PHP file. It should be just as easy as adding a properly formatted readme.txt to the root directory of a plugin, right? I've tried that. I've tried putting default generated files in that place. I've tried putting readme files there that I know work from other plugins. What gives? I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing but I can't figure out what it is. Google searches have been no help so far. What are some likely culprits I can check through?

Comment: "View Details" gets information from wordpress.org, not readme.txt (although wordpress.org uses the readme). So if your plugin is not listed on wordpress.org it won't show up. There might be a way to add your own, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Pretty sure [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/203841/31073) still applies.

Comment: @JacobPeattie That makes a lot of sense. Then my question becomes this. We have a lot of Pro plugins that can't be downloaded off of wordpress.org. All of which have fully populated "View Details". How does that work?